# Local and Cloud DB 2 ways replication

Tags: mysql, database, replication, cloud-hosting, amazon-rds

Is it possible to have 2 ways replication between local database and cloud database?

for example any update on local DB (MySQL or MS SQL) will be replicated to database on Amazon Cloud and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have 2-way replication between local DB and cloud DB.
However, you might want to consider the following before deciding to implement such replication:

1. Cost: Hosting providers charge for both input and output actions in
   the data center, so this can hike up what you are paying.
2. Performance: Network latency which can affect data traffic between
   local and hosted databases.
3. Reliability: If for some reason your local DB shuts down, then the
   replication will be interrupted, which can of course cause issues.

You should perhaps consider looking into keeping your DB in the cloud, and instead of a two-way replication check what type of local backup and access the different vendors offer. :)

Comment: It's a desktop application and reading data for any and every instance wouldn't be advisable. Replication helps me to keep the data backed up and in sync with web app.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Cloud VMs are just regular servers, so you just have to setup a classical two-way replication, but naturally due to Internet latencies and your own bandwidth, it might cause problems in some cases such as inserting/updating/deleting a huge batch of data